# .net core webapi not working with .net toolkit extension on linux Plesk after deployment

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, plesk

I am using Plesk on Linux VPS (ubuntu) i am using .NET Toolkit as extension. When i try to deploy the .net Web API developed in 6.0 and publish profile as (linux-x64) it's not working.

After deployment when i try to run the site it's not working and getting 404.

Comment: What logs do you have when you start the application by hand in the console?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek Getting nginx SSL/TLS access in the Plesk Panel with 404 Status

Comment: There is no code and there are no details.